# Is it faster to check if length = 0 than to compare it to an empty string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I've heard that in some programming languages it is faster to check if the length of a string is `0`, than to check if the content is `""`. Is this also true for T-SQL?

Sample:

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE LEN(user_email) = 0
```

vs.

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email = ''
```

Comment: Dear espo you have heard it right, reason being the string is implemented in the programming languages as a class and length is this class's variable. Hence accessing a variable is faster than running a function to get the answer. In sql you have to call the function to get the length which is slower than comparing with the empty string or null.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Edit**
You've updated your question since I first looked at it. In that example I would say that you should definitely always use

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email = ''
```

**Not**

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE LEN(user_email) = 0
```

The first one will allow an index to be used. As a performance optimisation this will trump some string micro optimisation every time! To see this

```
SELECT * into #temp FROM [master].[dbo].[spt_values]

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix ON #temp([name],[number])

SELECT [number] FROM #temp WHERE [name] = ''

SELECT [number] FROM #temp WHERE LEN([name]) = 0
```

Execution Plans

[image: Execution Plans]

**Original Answer**

In the code below (SQL Server 2008 - I "borrowed" the timing framework from [@8kb's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201982/having-transaction-in-all-queries/3273661#3273661)) I got a slight edge for testing the length rather than the contents below when `@stringToTest` contained a string. They were equal timings when NULL. I probably didn't test enough to draw any firm conclusions though.

In a typical execution plan I would imagine the difference would be negligible and if you're doing that much string comparison in TSQL that it will be likely to make any significant difference you should probably be using a different language for it.

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME2
DECLARE @testContents INT
DECLARE @testLength INT

SET @testContents = 0
SET @testLength = 0


DECLARE 
  @count INT,
  @value INT,
  @stringToTest varchar(100)


set @stringToTest = 'jasdsdjkfhjskdhdfkjshdfkjsdehdjfk'
SET @count = 1

WHILE @count < 10000000
BEGIN

  SET @date = GETDATE()
  SELECT @value = CASE WHEN @stringToTest = '' then 1 else 0 end
  SET @testContents = @testContents + DATEDIFF(MICROSECOND, @date, GETDATE())

  SET @date = GETDATE()
  SELECT @value = CASE WHEN len(@stringToTest) = 0 then 1 else 0 end
  SET @testLength = @testLength + DATEDIFF(MICROSECOND, @date, GETDATE())

  SET @count = @count + 1
END

SELECT 
  @testContents / 1000000. AS Seconds_TestingContents, 
  @testLength / 1000000. AS Seconds_TestingLength
```

Answer (score 7):

I would be careful about using `LEN` in a `WHERE` clause as it could lead to table or index scans.

Also note that if the field is `NULL`able that `LEN(NULL) = NULL`, so you would need to define the behaviour, e.g.:

```
-- Cost .33
select * from [table]
where itemid = ''

-- Cost .53
select * from [table]
where len(itemid) = 0

-- `NULL`able source field (and assuming we treat NULL and '' as the same)
select * from [table]
where len(itemid) = 0 or itemid is NULL
```

Answer (score 5):

I just tested it in a very limited scenario and execution plan ever so slightly favours comparing it to an empty string. (49% to 51%). This is working with stuff in memory though so it would probably be different if comparing against data from a table.

```
DECLARE @testString nvarchar(max)
SET @testString = ''

SELECT
    1
WHERE
    @testString = ''

SELECT
    1
WHERE
    LEN(@testString) = 0
```

Edit: This is with SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer depends largely on the context. For example, I have been working with expressions in the SELECT list and in user-defined functions. Knowing what I do about the Microsoft .NET Base Class Library and the legacy that Transact-SQL owes to Visual Basic, I suspect that in such circumstances, **LEN ( string )** gets the nod.