# why should I use Len(columnName) instead of columnName='' (sql server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Just wondering 
I colleague said to me don't use `columnName=''` instead use `Len(columnName)==0`

This happened when I was querying something and I wanted all columns in my table where the value was null or empty.

Is there any benefit in using len i/o testing for empty string? I cannot see any.

thanks

Comment: Generally you don't want to be wrapping columns in function calls as this is unsargable and means that both indexes and column statistics can't be used. possible duplicate of [Is it faster to check if length = 0 than to compare it to an empty string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350959/is-it-faster-to-check-if-length-0-than-to-compare-it-to-an-empty-string)

Comment: @Martin Smith It seems like `Len` *could* be sargable though ... if it was chosen to be implemented as such an optimization (all the strings with the same length are consecutive in an index) so it could be transformed to (the intent-equivalent of) `name > "AAA" and name < "ZZZ"`. I have no idea if such an optimization is applied, or what the real-world performance impact of the indexes (if any) are though, just a musing.

Comment: @pst all the strings with the same length are not consecutive in an index, they are ordered lexicographically according to collation rules?

Comment: @Martin Smith Doh. You're absolutely correct. I'm not quite sure what I was thinking there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the rows where the value is empty string or null you should do like this.

```
where Col = '' or Col is null
```

Using `len(Col)` will not give you the the rows with `null` values.

Comment: interesting .Didnt know that would not give row with null values

Comment: i just saw this post and want to notice, that NULLs aren't values. NULL is just a marker for a missing or inapplicable value. But an empty string '' is a value. That's the difference. So when a column allows NULLs be sure you handle those in TSQL