# Linq == null vs IsNullOrEmpty -- Different or Same?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

In `Linq` or `Linq to Sql` to be more accurate: is there a difference between the `== null` and the `IsNullOrEmpty` in the below queries?

```
From a in context.SomeTable
where a.SomeId.Equals(SomeOtherId)
&& a.SomeOtherColumn == null
Select new .....
```

&

```
From a in context.SomeTable
where a.SomeId.Equals(SomeOtherId)
&& string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.SomeOtherColumn)
Select new .....
```

Comment: Well I don't know linq but SQl Server would consider empty string and NUll as two differnt things (this needing two differnt commands) while Oracle may not. So I would bet for some databases it makes a differnce and in others it does not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do `String.IsNullOrEmpty` in Linq-SQL:

> Method 'Boolean IsNullOrEmpty(System.String)' has no supported
>   translation to SQL.

If you need that, I guess you will have to have both the null and empty check in your where clause:

```
&& (a.SomeOtherColumn == null || a.SomeOtherColumn == "")
```

Which will translate to a null and empty check in SQL.

Looking at the other answers, using `.Length == 0`, will generate SQL to check the length of the varchar column, which may be less efficient than checking if a varchar is equal to `''`.

**EDIT:** Here's a Stack Overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3351074/383710) on Length versus Empty check for SQL. It seems I guessed right.

Answer (score 1):

The string.IsNullOrEmpty also applies to an empty string like `""`

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious difference is in the name. [`IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) also checks whether the string is empty. It would be equivalent to:

```
from a in context.SomeTable
where a.SomeId.Equals(SomeOtherId)
&& (a.SomeOtherColumn == null || a.SomeOtherColumn.Length == 0)
...
```

Or

```
from a in context.SomeTable
where a.SomeId.Equals(SomeOtherId)
&& (a.SomeOtherColumn == null || a.SomeOtherColumn == "")
...
```

Answer (score 1):

While other answers have stated the obvious fact that `.IsNullOrEmpty()` checks for empty strings, it's also important to note that the comparison

```
where a.SomeOtherColumn == someNullVariable
```

will **never** return any values in LINQ-to-SQL, due to using SQL null-comparisons rather than C# null-comparisons.  [This is actually a bug in LINQ-to-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14302701/238419).

Answer (score 0):

`IsNullOrEmpty` is equal to

```
s == null || s.Length == 0;
```

Where `s` is instance of `string`