# C# and SQL Server: any reason to put a single INSERT into a transaction?

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

Using C# and SQL Server, would there be any reason to put a single INSERT statement into a transaction?

I am reviewing code written by someone else.  I can't understand why a transaction would be needed since there is only one SQL statement.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201982/having-transaction-in-all-queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programmatically, there would be no reason. The reason might be in readability though; wrapping an arbitrary code snippet in a transaction is a pretty good way of drawing the attention of future developers to it - or away from something else.
It might also just be that the Best Practice at the time of writing was to wrap any dealings with the database in a transaction, just as wrapping stuff in try/catch-blocks.

My suggestion: If the code is clearer and more readable because of this, or if all other database calls are in transactions, leave it in. Otherwise, remove it.

Answer (score 9):

It will already be in an [implicit transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188317.aspx). No need to wrap it in another redundant transaction.

Comment: An `INSERT` statement is atomic, but it doesn't use an implicit transaction (at least not the type described in that link). If that were the case then an explicit `COMMIT` would be required.

Comment: @Luke - It does use implicit transactions. There is a `set` option as well though also called implicit transactions which is what I think the link is referring to.

Comment: @Luke Actually it looks like the preferred term may be auto commit transactions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187878.aspx I've always just thought explicit vs implicit as well.

Answer (score 3):

No reason at all.