# Does it make sense to begin a transaction where there will be only some data-retrieval operations?

Tags: sql, transactions

Does it make sense to begin a transaction where there will be only some data-retrieval operations and no UPDATE or INSERT will occur?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having TRANSACTION In All Queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201982/having-transaction-in-all-queries)

Answer (score 2):

Not normally.

If you have 2 SELECTs they *could* become inconsistent in the fraction of second between reads.

A transaction won't fix this for SQL Server/Sybase type locking because read locks will be released. So you'd need to use higher isolation levels which will affect concurrency (potentially quite  [serious](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2011/06/23/inappropriate-usage-of-high-isolation-level-isn-t-just-about-blocking-when-it-comes-to-performance.aspx))

The trade off between "tiny risk of inconsistent data" and "loss of performance" is up to you.

Comment: +1 I will add, however, under pessimistic concurrency model, there are scenarios where even a single SELECT can cause an inconsistent read when primary key is updated by another connection.(i.e. same row may appear in the selected data more than once with different primary keys). This is definitely possible under READ COMMITTED isolation on SQL Server.

Comment: @Chris Bednarski: agree, but generally PKs are unchanging of course.

Answer (score 0):

Starting a transaction for that case insures that the data seen will be consistent; some other process will not be able to update the rows you are looking at such that the second `SELECT` sees something different from the first when it should be seeing the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, to ensure transaction-leven read consistency.

> Ensuring Repeatable Reads with Read-Only Transactions
>
> By default, the consistency model for Oracle guarantees statement-level read consistency, but does not guarantee transaction-level read consistency (repeatable reads). If you want transaction-level read consistency, and if your transaction does not require updates, then you can specify a read-only transaction. After indicating that your transaction is read-only, you can execute as many queries as you like against any database table, knowing that the results of each query in the read-only transaction are consistent with respect to a single point in time.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg08sql.htm

Comment: Too localised, doesn't apply to SQL Server/Sybase

Comment: @gbn [SNAPSHOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) for MSSQL [SNAPSHOT transaction](http://dcx.sybase.com/1101/en/dbusage_en11/transact-s-4136352.html) for Sybase, isn't this the same behaviour?

Comment: It isn't the default and will revert to the normal locking on occasion so you'd get unexpected behaviour...